# Vite and conditional dead code elimination

Tags: javascript, vite, dead-code, code-elimination

I use Vite bundler and in my code I have the following function:

```js
function doSomething() {
  if (!import.meta.env.VITE_SOMETHING) {
    return;
  }

  console.log("Hello");
}
```

I would expect that after building my app (`npm run build`) without defining `VITE_SOMETHING` env var I will see no `Hello` logging in the code, but I see it.

What is worse, on every place where I used `import.meta.env.VITE_SOMETHING` I see in the compiled output `{BASE_URL:"/",MODE:"production",DEV:!1,PROD:!0}.VITE_SOMETHING`. It does't looks very optimal.

Is it possible co configure Vite to optimize the output - remove unused code and duplications (which it introduced)?

Answer (score 1):

In current vite version it works as expected.
This is example of correct configuration
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-cqttnd?file=tree-shaked/main.ts